# Inflation foreign demand question

Tags: macroeconomics

I’m in AP macroeconomics so I don’t really know anything, but I came across this question that didn’t make sense to me.

The table shows the macroeconomic statistics for the country of Fehran.
|Year|…|GDP Deflator|
| -------- | -------------- | ----- |
| 2011    | …           | 100 |
| 2012   | …            | 125 |
*there’s some other useless information in the table*

First it asks you the inflation rate from 2011 to 2012, which is obviously 25%.

Then it asks: Fehran is the only producer and exporter of electric vehicles. Assume the price level among Fehran’s trading partners remains the same and the inflation rate of Fehran is reflective of price changes for electric vehicles. As a result of the change in the relative price level, would foreign importers buy more or fewer electric vehicles from Fehran in 2012 compared to 2011?

The answer they provide is that the higher prices of the EVs leads to less demand. But I don’t quite get that. It seems to me that the inflation in Fehran should lead to their currency becoming less valuable. Then shouldn’t that offset the increases in price?